# Chromeが正常に起動しない

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

ある時からgoogle Chromeがウインドウが表示されるものの、中身が表示されず真っ白な状態です
他のブラウザは正常です。ローカルファイルをChromeで開こうとしても真っ白です
環境はubuntu 20.04です

端末から以下コードで削除

```
sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable
```

再起動後以下のディレクトリを削除

```
/home/user/.cache/google-chrome
/home/user/.config/google-chrome
```

以下コードで再インストール

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

起動すると「chromeへようこそ」のウィンドウが生成されますが中身が白いまま表示されていません
正常に起動できるよう対処方法のアドバイスをお願いします

Comment: googleのサイトから chromeダウンロードして (`*.deb`) それをインストールするとよいかも。`sudo dpkg -i ファイル名.deb`。もしくは Flatpakで行うか

Comment: 書いてませんが公式サイトの*.debも駄目でしたがflatpakでうまく行きそうです

Comment: すみません、回答ではありません。
私もまったく同じ状態です。
win10ホスト　vIrtualboxでLubuntu20.04です。Flatpakでもインストールできず、
同じ環境で　Kubuntu 20.04では公式サイトの*.debで正常にインストールできています。

Comment: 回答の手順でインストールできないのであればログを明示して新たに質問するのが良いと思います

Comment: ちなみに当方Lubuntu22.04へ環境が変わっているのですが、こちらは公式debで問題なく動作しています。20.04はサポートも切れるので環境を変えてしまうのも手だと思います

Comment: @user61532 Flatpakの件は後藤喜一さんのコメントの通りと思いますが、deb によるインストールも、Lubuntu（LXQt）とUbuntu（GNOME）では事情が異なりますので、新たに別の質問として投稿いただくのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatpakにてchromeをインストールし、起動出来ました

ある程度新しいflatpakのバージョンが必要なので
端末で以下のようにflatpakをインストールしてから
chromeをインストールする必要がありました

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak install com.google.Chrome
```

正常なcache、configディレクトリをコピーしてaptからインストールしたものに使用しようと思いましたが
症状は治りませんでした

```
/home/user/.var/app/com.google.Chrome/cache/google-chrome
/home/user/.var/app/com.google.Chrome/config/google-chrome
```